# AFNetworking SSL issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with AFNetworking securityPolicy and with ssl.
I added all this

```
self.manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        AFSecurityPolicy* policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];

        [policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
        [policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
        self.manager.securityPolicy = policy;
```

but et this error

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

what else I have to add.

Comment: did you set "App transport security" in plist ?

Comment: Yes. 
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Answer (score 0):

Add App `Transport Security Settings` to your `pList` like [image]

Comment: I added it,it doesnt  help

Comment: you sure this object is retain?

Comment: I am sure,because same code works,when I change my url.

Comment: There is some problem with SSL,invalid sertificate,or something like that